# perl -> Parsing json string of hash

Tags: arrays, json, perl, hash

so I took a curl output of a json formatted output and assigned it to a variable.

```
my $catcherJSON = decode_json $response->content;
print Dumper $catcherJSON;
```

When I view the $catcherJSON, I want to see an array of hashes, but I just get a massive string of json.

```
$VAR1 = [
      {
        'priority' => 5,
        'ingestPath' => '/vg/24CHVOD_en',
...
...
...
      },
      {
        'priority' => 5,
        'ingestPath' => 
...
...
      },
      {
        'priority' => 5,
        'ingestPath' => 

... 
...  
      },
      {
        'priority' => 5,
        'ingestPath' => 

 ...
 ...},
      {
        'priority' => 5,
        'ingestPath' => 
  ....
  ...                 
      }
    ];
```

The hashes repeat (There are about 300 unique results) and I'm trying to figure out in perl how I can split this 1 string into my array of hashes simply.

Any way that I can easily convert this into a proper array of hashes so I can iterate through it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

> *Any way that I can easily convert this into a proper array of hashes so I can iterate through it?*

You've already done it.

> *so I took a curl output of a json formatted output and assigned it to a variable.*
>
> ```
> my $catcherJSON = decode_json $response->content;`
> ```

That's not correct.

You took the JSON formatted string from `$response->content`, decoded the JSON into a Perl data structure, and stored it in `$catcherJSON`.

> *When I view the $catcherJSON, I want to see an array of hashes, but I just get a massive string of json.*

`$catcherJSON` is not a string of JSON. `$catcherJSON` is a Perl array of hashes. You've already decoded the JSON into a Perl data structure with `decode_json`. It's been formatted by [`Dumper()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper) back into Perl code so you can read it.

Your code is fine, you have what you want. For example, `$catcherJSON->[0]{ingestPath}` will be `'/vg/24CHVOD_en'`.

Comment: `It's been formatted by Dumper() back into Perl code.` -- into the string.

Comment: This got me closer so I appreciate the help.

Comment: Just need some further help as it's now throwing another error.   Need to check again and will post the error that is now showing up

Comment: print Dumper $catcherJSON->[0]{id};  
Can't use string ("[ {
  "id" : "128",
  "name" : ""...) as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at ./avcm.catchers.parse.pl line 81.

Comment: @JeffGrubb `my $catcherJSON = decode_json $response->content; print Dumper $catcherJSON->[0]{id};` should work. Your error suggests you removed the `decode_json`.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $catcherJSON = $response->content;
$catcherJSON =~ s/\n//g;
$catcherJSON = decode_json($catcherJSON);
```

This was my eventual solution.
When the curl response comes in, all json has line breaks.  As soon as line breaks are removed, my decode_json will now refence all as $catcherJSON->[0]{id}, etc...

Thanks everyone for the help here.
Much appreciated.